# Flutter | SQFLite - obtaining index difficulty in stateless widget

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am trying to insert a row of data into a sqflite db with three columns

- id
- value of water consumed
- date
  I want to use the date so that for every day, there will be one set of data since every day will get one date. and later update it if the user wished to increase the value of water drank on that day.

this the widget in charge of a group of buttons. it will hold the db commands to insert and update. My issue here is that i have no need for a builder and therefore cant induce a "index" variable which i can use to filter my values in my table - i dont know how to go about it as i am only familiar with this method.

```
class WaterButtonsGrouped extends StatelessWidget {


//past here are my attempts to fix this issue- didnt work
  int? WaterDrank = 0;
  late int TotalWaterDrank = 0;

   WaterButtonsGrouped({super.key});

  String date = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.now());
  String dateNow = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.now());

  var _filteredInputs = [];

  getUserInputDate() async {
     _filteredInputs = await WaterDBHelper.getWaterDateFilter();
     print('1 ${_filteredInputs.length}');
     return _filteredInputs;
  }
  addInput(WaterButtonModel)  {
    print('${WaterButtonModel.waterMillimeters} ml');
    WaterDrank = WaterButtonModel.waterMillimeters;
    TotalWaterDrank = TotalWaterDrank + WaterDrank!;

    print(date);
    getUserInputDate();
    checkDate();

    return  TotalWaterDrank;
  }
  addWater() {
    return TotalWaterDrank;
  }
  // date in db is equal to date-now then 2 options
  checkDate() async {
    if (_filteredInputs.isNotEmpty) {
      //insert
      print('insert command ran - ${TotalWaterDrank}');

      _addWater();
    }
    else {
      //update milliliters
      print('update command ran - ${TotalWaterDrank}');

      _updateWaterThrouDate(dateNow);
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


//buttons that will be shown from this widget - not important
    return Wrap(
      children: [

        WaterButton(
          buttonModel: WaterButtonModel.cup(),
          onPressed: addInput,
        ),
        WaterButton(
          buttonModel: WaterButtonModel.glass(),
          onPressed: addInput,
        ),
        WaterButton(
          buttonModel: WaterButtonModel.bottle(),
          onPressed: addInput,
        ),
        WaterButton(
          buttonModel: WaterButtonModel.canister(),
          onPressed: addInput,
        ),

      ],
    );

  }

//db commands
  Future <void> _addWater() async {
    await WaterDBHelper.insertWater(
        date,
        TotalWaterDrank
    );
  }
  Future <void> _updateWater(int id) async {
    await WaterDBHelper.updateWaterDrank(
        id,
        TotalWaterDrank,
    );
  }
  Future <void> _updateWaterThrouDate(String date) async {
    await WaterDBHelper.updateWaterDrankThrouDate(
        date,
        TotalWaterDrank
    );
  }

}
```

my database is working correctly after tests, i am very comfortable with creating dbhelpers - no issues here.

here is my "main" page that will link all associated data. it will present the group of buttons above and a circular progress indicator that i have linked below.

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget> [
    
                SizedBox(height: 15),
    
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    "Hydration Level",
                    style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                      fontSize: 50,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
    
                SizedBox(height: 50),
    
                Container(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                  child: WaterProgressIndicator(WaterDrank: addedWater()),
                ),
    
                SizedBox(height: 50),
    
                WaterButtonsGrouped(),
    
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
        addedWater()  {
        int TotalWaterDrank =  WaterButtonsGrouped().addWater();
        return  TotalWaterDrank!;
      }
    
    }



here is the indicator. this will receive the data from the WaterButtonsGrouped() class and send any information to update the values here.

class WaterProgressIndicator extends StatefulWidget {

  int? WaterDrank;

  WaterProgressIndicator({
     this.WaterDrank,
  });


  @override
  State<WaterProgressIndicator> createState() => _WaterProgressIndicatorState(WaterDrank!);
}

class _WaterProgressIndicatorState extends State<WaterProgressIndicator> {

  late double Percentage = 0;
  int WaterGoal = 2000;


  int WaterDrank;
  _WaterProgressIndicatorState(this.WaterDrank);

  PercentageTotal()  {
    setState(() {
       Percentage = WaterDrank / WaterGoal;
    });
    return Percentage;
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      PercentageTotal();
      print('${Percentage * 100} %');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return LiquidCircularProgressIndicator(
        value: PercentageTotal(),
        borderColor: Colors.blue.shade800,
        borderWidth: 7.0,
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        center: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Text(
                '${PercentageTotal() * 100} %',
                style: GoogleFonts.deliciousHandrawn(
                  color: Colors.blue.shade700,
                  fontSize: 100,
                )),
            Text(
                'DRANK',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 25,
                )),
            Text('TOTAL',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                  fontSize: 20,
                )),
          ],
        )

    );
  }
}
```

.Just to reiterate. The Water() class will be the final location to where all the data will be stored.

.The WaterButtonsGrouped() class will be in-charge of the functionality of the buttons, here is where i'm having troubles as i can insert data into db but not update it as for some reason my if operator is not workings as intended

.progress indicator will receive updated data from either the db or WaterButtonsGrouped() class - i have not finished it as i am stuck with the index problem

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking or what your issue is. Can you reduce your code to the minimal reproducible example and state what the expected vs. actual behaviour is?

Comment: @puelo, thank you for looking into it, i have edited it to link appropriate code and more explanation. I just want to be able to get the index without the builder is the most basic summary of my problem.

Comment: I can see two potential issues: 1. isn't the condition in `checkDate()` backwards? Shouldn't the first check be `if (_filteredInputs.isEmpty) {`? 2. In `addInput` you call the async function `getUserInputDate`but are not awaiting its result. Instead you proceed with the next function which depends on the data loaded in there.

Comment: @puelo, i played around the two aspects you mentioned and it has no affect on the outcome. the problem is that im unable to obtain the index of the inserted data

Answer (score 0):

In my weird case it was working fine. i only had to delete the db and have it created again.